# Overreleasing issue and Zombies

Tags: objective-c, debugging, nszombies

this program crashes if i uncomment the release statements. i get that i am overreleasing and realized that quickly. but, just to test zombies, i turned them on (NSZombiesEnabled = YES and CFZombieLevel = 16) and the program runs fine and throws no exceptions.

what gives? i thought turning on zombies would have just told me what a doofus i am...not fix it.

```
#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController

-(IBAction)countCharacters:(id)sender   {
    //did a button do this?
if(![sender isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]])    {
    NSLog(@"%@ is not a button", sender);
    return;
}

//proceed
NSString *userString = [textField stringValue];
NSNumber *count = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[userString length]];
NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' has %@ characters.",
                        userString, count];
//[userString release];
//[count release];
[labelField setStringValue:outputString];
//[outputString release];
}
@end
```

Comment: Why don't you change (id)sender to (NSButton*)sender in -(IBAction)countCharacters:? That way you won't have to check. Unless this is not only called through the GUI.

Comment: @zneak;  that doesn't make sense.  An action method is always `-(IBAction)selector:(id) sender`.  And whether or not you check is entirely orthogonal to how target/action works.

Comment: @bbum; It does make sense. Explicitly telling what kind of object you expect to send the action makes it impossible in Interface Builder to assign the action to any other type of object. Which is obviously what he wants. I just double-checked in case I did say something utterly stupid, and it behaves exactly the way I describe it.

Comment: Yup. You are correct. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you do not own the objects you try to release (you don't hold a reference to them). Their ownership is given to the "nearest" NSAutoreleasePool.

You can read about object ownership [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html). As a quick reference, usually, you aren't the owner if you didn't call the `alloc` method yourself to create the object or if you didn't `retain` it. `Retain`ing an object makes you an owner; calling `release` means you give up ownership (and will deallocate the object if it has no more owners).

You **must not** release objects for which you don't have ownership. Your current code without release is exactly what you need.

Comment: Exactly correct.  In other words, if you were to uncomment the commented lines, then run Zombies, the zombie logging mechanism would trigger.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. i knew i shouldn't release them, but it didn't click as to why not.

Comment: If it isn't triggering and you know the autorelease poole is being drained, please file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Well, zombies will tell you when a free'd object receives a release correct? So, if your not sending the release (you commented it out) you won't see the zombies complaining?

Your NSString/NSNumber methods are all convenience methods, and you don't have to release them. So -yeah, You solved the problem yourself.